# How to return a value from a function in Java?

Tags: java

I can't get this code to work and I don't know why. Is it possible to return the value from calculateTotal method? I'm new to programming and Java is my first one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ass2ques2draft
{
public static Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
 public static void main (String[]args)
 {
int addOrder;
 do {
 System.out.println ("**************************");
 System.out.println ("WELCOME TO LILY BAKERY");
 System.out.println ("**************************");
 System.out.println ("Please choose your preferred cake code:");
 System.out.println (" ");
 System.out.println ("1 - New York Cheese");
 System.out.println ("2 - Black Forest Cheese");
 System.out.println ("3 - Oreo Cheese ");
 System.out.println ("4 - Chocolate Indulgence Cake");
 System.out.println ("5- Turkish Indulgence");
 System.out.println ("6- Red Velvet");
 System.out.println ("7- Fruitilicious");

 takeOrder();
 System.out.print ("Do you want to add your order? :  1 - \"Y\" /  2 -\"N\" :" );
 addOrder = scan.nextInt();
 }while (addOrder == 1);
 double totalPrice = calculateTotal( cakeChoice , quantity );

 System.out.printf ("Total price : RM %.2f %n " , totalPrice);
 System.out.print ("Please enter amount tendered : RM");
 double amountTendered =scan.nextDouble();
 double balance = amountTendered-totalPrice;

 System.out.println ("Your transaction :");
 System.out.println ("*****************" );
 System.out.printf ("Total Price : %.2f %n" , totalPrice );
 System.out.printf ("Amount Tendered : %.2f %n" , amountTendered);
 System.out.printf ("Balance : %.2f%n" , balance);
 System.out.println ("*****************************************************");
 System.out.println (" " );
 System.out.println ("$$$$$$$$$$$$--THANK YOU & PLEASE COME AGAIN !!! --$$$$$");


 }//main

 public static void takeOrder()
 {
  System.out.print("Enter your choice of cake : ");
  int cakeChoice = scan.nextInt();
  if ( cakeChoice == 1 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of New York Cheese : ");
  } 

  else if ( cakeChoice == 2 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Black Forest Cheese : ");
  } 

  else if ( cakeChoice == 3 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Oreo Cheese : ");
  } 
  else if ( cakeChoice == 4 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Chocolate Indulgence Cake : ");
  }
 else if ( cakeChoice == 5 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Turkish Indulgence : ");
  } 
  else if ( cakeChoice == 6 )
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Red Velvet : ");
  }
  else  if  ( cakeChoice == 7 )
  {
  System.out.print ("Enter the quantity of Fruitilicious : ");  
  }
  int quantity=scan.nextInt(); 

  calculateTotal (cakeChoice , quantity );
  }//takeOrder

  public static double calculateTotal ( int cakeChoice, int quantity )
  {
   double price;

   if ( cakeChoice <5 )
   {
   price = 88*quantity;
   }
   else
   {
   price=130*quantity;
   }
 double totalPrice=0;
  totalPrice += price;
  return totalPrice;

  }//calculateTotal
  }//class
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use more and more prominent indentation.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to Java, you might not be knowing the convention, always start the name of the class with a CAPITAL letter. Your code is buggy.
Where have you defined **cakeChoice & quantity** at the class level?

These are undefined variables.
Yes the method can return the total .

Declare the variables `cakeChoice & quantity` at the class level. These variables you have made **local** to the method **takeOrder**. I would suggest making the code this way

```
    public class Ass2ques2draft
{
 int cakeChoice; // declare them here
 int quantity;  // 
public static Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
```

Do not declare them in the takeOrder method, instead use them straight away. And do not pass them to calculateTotal method

In take order method, make it

```
  System.out.print("Enter your choice of cake : ");
  cakeChoice = scan.nextInt(); // This uses the class level member,instead of making a new local variable as cakeChoice
```

And simply call the calculate method, without passing any args.

```
public static double calculateTotal (  )
  {
   double price;

   if ( cakeChoice <5 ) // use the class level variable cakeChoice
   {
   price = 88*quantity; // use the class level quantitiy
   } 
   else
   {
   price=130*quantity;
   }
 double totalPrice=0;
  totalPrice += price;
  return totalPrice;

  }//calculateTotal
  }//class
```

The main problem with your code is that you are creating new "local" variables everytime in every method. Also line no 81 has no signficance. What will you do with the returned total here ?

Comment: But line no 26 will be prolematic : double totalPrice = calculateTotal( cakeChoice , quantity );

Comment: The variables cakeChoice and quanitity are local to method takeOrder. He is calling takeOrder method which calls calculateTotal, but the price returned from calculateTotal goes nowhere

Answer (score 0):

For readability I'd definetly recommend using a switch statement instead of the nested `if`s:

```
System.out.print("Enter your choice of cake : ");
int cakeChoice = scan.nextInt();
switch(cakeChoice) {
    case 1: System.out.println("Enter the quantity of xy"); break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Enter the quantity of yz"); break;
    //...
    default: System.out.println("Invalid cake order!"); takeOrder();
}
calculateTotal (cakeChoice , scan.nextInt() );
```

And for the price you can simply do it like this:

```
return (cakeChoice < 5)? (double) 88*quantity :  (double)130*quantity;
```

Unless you're working with decimal prices you can change the return value of your function to `int` and remove the `double` casts.